# What is this code's meaning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was designing a webpage and encountered the following code written in javascript I want to know if it's ok if i remove this code and add my own code or does it create any problems Note: This was an code found in an HTML5 Template

Here is the code:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code selects all HTML elements that have a CSS class of `js-switch` applied and creates a new Switchery object for each of them. Since you didn't provide much context I have to guess but it's very likely that this will turn standard HTML checkboxes into iOS-style switches.

See also the Switchery homepage for more information: http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/

Whether this code is needed or not might be a design decision. It'll only change the visual appearance but the sliders still behave like checkboxes. It might, however, be worth checking whether your site actually contains any HTML checkboxes with the `js-switch` class applied. If not, that code can definitely be dropped.

Comment: Actually I don't have check boxes for which this piece of javascript is written!! So is that ok if I remove the code?

Comment: @Vasu_candy If there are no checkboxes at all on your site, I would say so.